# Unable to retrieve Marketing Cloud/ExactTarget SOAP Api SubscriberSendResult Object

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, triggered-send

Good morning,

I am trying to retrieve the SubscriberSendResult object via Marketing Cloud's SOAP Api with no success.  I receive an OK status with no results.  I have tried filtering using simple filters on SentDate, Send.ID, Subscriber.SubscriberKey, Subscriber.EmailAddress, and a few others, but the response is the same every time.

I have no problem retrieving the SentEvent object using filters or not. I also have no problem retrieving the Send object using a SendID from a SentEvent result. I just can not seem to be able to retrieve the SubscriberSendResult for individual Subscriber tracking on one of my sends.

Any help is appreciated.

Mike

Comment: Ok, I have figured out that the objects I need to retrieve are in fact the Bounce, Sent, Click, Open, etc. objects.  There may or may not be one of these for a SendID/BatchID combination so Ill need to composite results for this approach.  

I am now stuck on Send Logging to a DataExtension for Triggered Sends...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SubscriberSendResult is the wrong object.  It does appear there will be individual objects created for a BounceEvent, ClickEvent, OpenEvent, etc.  Can retrieve SentEvents to get BatchIDs and SendIDs then get these other objects filtering on those.

It would be really nice to be able to get a summary of Subscriber activity by SendID/BatchID if there are any Marketing Cloud Devs out there looking for new featuresets...